# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I need help filtering an array of objects in a typescript react native project using state to store array values and filter objects in the array

see error I keep getting in the method in question

```
cannot read property push of undefined
```

Appearing this way

```
 LOG   after item
 LOG  inside 300
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined, js engine: hermes
```

see my code below

```
 const handleSearchButtonPressed = () => {
    console.log("inside handleSearchButtonPressed")
    if (!itemListStore){
      return
    }
    const text = searchText.toLowerCase()
    console.log("inside 100")

    // array of output objects
    // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
    const filteredObjs =  itemListStore.filter((item) => {
      console.log(" 200")
      console.log(" item is ")
      console.log(item)
      console.log(" after item")
      const strTitle = JSON.stringify(item.title)
      const strDesc = JSON.stringify(item.description)
      const strLink = JSON.stringify(item.link)

      const itemObj = {
        title:strTitle,
        description: strDesc,
        link: strLink
      }

      if (strTitle.toLowerCase().match(text)) {
        console.log("inside 300")

        filteredObjs.push(itemObj)
        console.log("inside 400")

      }
    })

    console.log("filteredObjs", filteredObjs)
    if (!text || text === "") {
      setSearchText("",
      )
    } else if (!Array.isArray(filteredObjs) && !filteredObjs.length) {
      // set no data flag to true so as to render flatlist conditionally
      setNoData(true)

    } else if (Array.isArray(filteredObjs)) {
      setNoData(false)
      setItemListStore(filteredObjs)
    }

  }
```

Comment: It's filtering or... mapping? I think you have mistaken both of those functions, like trying to mix them together somehow. Filter expects a condition - boolean to be returned.

Comment: You're trying to use the `filteredObjects` variable within the `filter()` callback that defines it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to both [*filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). This can more easily be achieved using either two separate operations or one single [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Two operations...

```js
const filteredObjs = itemListStore
  .filter(({ title }) => title.toLowerCase().includes(text))
  .map(({ title, description, link }) => ({
    title: JSON.stringify(title),
    description: JSON.stringify(description),
    link: JSON.stringify(link),
  }));
```

One *reduce*...

```js
const filteredObjs = itemListStore.reduce(
  (arr, { title, description, link }) => {
    if (title.toLowerCase().includes(text)) {
      return [
        ...arr,
        {
          title: JSON.stringify(title),
          description: JSON.stringify(description),
          link: JSON.stringify(link),
        },
      ];
    }
    return arr;
  },
  []
);
```